# Error message comes up telling me it cannot find the folder after it has deleted it

Tags: c#, directory

What I'm trying to do is move the location of a folder, then copy the contents of another folder and move it to the parent directory and delete the original folder. All of that works great but after the process is done I get a weird error telling me it cannot find the folder it deleted and I can't figure out what's causing it look for the folder after it had already deleted it.

I had an exception that told me the error is`Directory.Move(FoundFolder, Path.GetFullPath(Setup.SelectedPath) + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(FoundFolder));`

This is the error message:

[image: error message]

Here's the code I tried:

```
string[] SetupFolderKeywords = { "Setup", "Installed" }; //keywords 
string[] roots = Directory.GetDirectories(Game.SelectedPath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly); //gets all directories in Game.SelectedP
foreach (var item in roots) //foreach directory found
{
    string? FoundFolder = Path.GetFullPath(item); //We get each path for each directory found
    if (FoundFolder.Contains(SetupFolderKeywords[1])) //if any of the found directories have any of the keywords
    {

        CopyDeleteFolder();
    }
    else if (FoundFolder.Contains(SetupFolderKeywords[0]))
    {
        CopyDeleteFolder();
        //unneccessary second pop up appears due to line 100
    }
}

public void CopyDeleteFolder()
{
    DirectoryInfo GameDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Game.SelectedPath);
    string GameContentsPath = Game.SelectedPath + @"\" + GameDirectory.Name; //inside of the game folder
    string[] roots = Directory.GetDirectories(Game.SelectedPath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (var item in roots)
    {
        string? FoundFolder = Path.GetFullPath(item);
        Directory.Move(FoundFolder, Path.GetFullPath(Setup.SelectedPath) + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(FoundFolder));
        if (Directory.Exists(GameContentsPath))
        {
            string[] GameFiles = Directory.GetFiles(GameContentsPath);
            foreach (string GameFile in GameFiles)
            {
                FileInfo CopyGameFile = new FileInfo(GameFile);
                if (new FileInfo(GameDirectory + @"\" + CopyGameFile.Name).Exists == false)
                {
                    CopyGameFile.MoveTo(GameDirectory + @"\" + CopyGameFile.Name);
                }
            }
            Directory.Delete(GameContentsPath);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing it's `roots` in `foreach var item in roots` but I'm not sure how to get around it.

`

Comment: *"I can't figure out what's causing it look for the folder"* - When you use a debugger, which specific operation produces the exception?

Comment: I think you might need to check `if (Directory.Exists(FoundFolder))` before doing `Directory.Move(FoundFolder...`

Comment: My English is not very good so I apologize if I misunderstood your question, but the line Directory.Move(FoundFolder, Path.GetFullPath(Setup.SelectedPath) + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(FoundFolder)); is where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @AhmedSherif: Then you *have* figured out what's causing it to look for the folder?  It's not really clear to me what you're asking.  You're performing an operation on the file system and the error is telling you that the directory was not found.  Do you expect the directory to be found?  Why or why not?  Do you not expect that line of code to be executed?  Why or why not?  Please elaborate on the specific question you're asking with regards to the specific debugging you've done.

Comment: @frankM_DN That worked. Thank you so much. I've tried plenty of things but that has not crossed my mind once. I'm sorry for making a post about something that is really easy compared to other posts on here.

Comment: @David Alright I'm really sorry I dropped a lot of necessary information. I will keep those in mind if I ever post on here again.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the 'Test Game' folder is being successfully moved on the first call to `CopyDeleteFolder` but (according to your error message) there is a second attempt to move it and predictably this will fail and throw the exception. It's easy to see why this would be the case if you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and simulate the Test Game folder as containing:

```
string[] roots = new[] { "MockGameSetup1", "MockGameInstalled" };
```

This simplified loop captures the essence of your original code and makes it easier to see that one condition will be true on the first loop iteration and the other will be true on the second loop iteration resulting in two calls to `CopyDeleteFolder`.

```
foreach (var item in roots) 
{
    if (item.Contains(SetupFolderKeywords[1]))
    {
        CopyDeleteFolder();
    }
    else if (item.Contains(SetupFolderKeywords[0]))
    {
        CopyDeleteFolder();
    }
}

void CopyDeleteFolder()
{
    // Move the 'Test Game' directory but only ONE time
}
```

One way to express **If any of the found directories have any of the keywords** is to use a `System.Linq` expression resulting in a single call to `CopyDeleteFolder`:

```
// Simulate names of folders contained.
string[] roots = new[] { "MockGameSetup1", "MockGameInstalled" };
string[] SetupFolderKeywords = { "Setup", "Installed" };

// If any of the found directories have any of the keywords 
if(roots.Any(path=>SetupFolderKeywords.Any(keyword=>path.Contains(keyword))))
{
    CopyDeleteFolder();
}
```